# How to display additional info on mouseover with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have an e-commerce simulation web app for buying movies and I want a popup small window to appear when a user mouses over the movie's id and display info and give them the option to add that movie to their cart (like how Facebook displays users info when you mouseover one of your friend's names). I have a java servlet that receives the movie's id and gets the proper info from my database and sends it back to the JSP, but form there I don't know how to properly use AJAX or jquery to display the window with the proper info.

**SERVLET CODE**

```
int movie_id = Integer.parseInt((String) request.getParameter("movie_id"));
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select * from movies where movies.id =");
    query.append(movie_id);

    // Perform the query
    MySQLHandler sql_handler = new MySQLHandler( );
    sql_handler.execute_query( query.toString() );
    ResultSet result = sql_handler.get_result();


    try {
        Movie movie = createMovie(result);

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(movie.getTitle());
        request.setAttribute("movie", movie);
    } 
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***JAVASCRIPT CODE***

```
function ajaxFunction(movie_id){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
}
alert(movie_id);
var parameter = "movie_id=" + movie_id;
ajaxRequest.open("POST","MoviePopUpWindowServlet", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type"
        , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") //Needed for post request for some reason. //http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml
ajaxRequest.send(parameter);
```

}

Comment: where is your code? what have you tried?

Comment: @threeFatCat sorry. I've edited the main post with the code

Comment: how about your template code? there are several ways you can display additional info on mouseover in your program since you have already the data. One way is you can use a `title` attribute and tooltip bootstrap (if you want). Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'route/to/videoinfo' + specificVideoId,
                type: "POST", 
                contentType: "application/json ;charset=UTF-8", 
            }).done(function(result){
                (if you rendered out the html already just do)
                var containerDiv = document.getElementById("#idOfDivToFill")
                containerDiv.innerHTML = result
            }).fail(function(err){
                console.log(err)
            })
```

Someone let me know if this is terrible.